# What is the baidu symbol in the notification bar mean?

Tags: security, notification-bar, notification-icons

After updating to MIUI 8.2.2.0 i have notices this persistent baidu symbol on my redmi note phone. [highlighted in red box, to the left of the alarm clock symbol]

I am unable to attribute this symbol to any of the background processes..?

should i be concerned privacy or similar such concerns?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think you were in MIUI Chinese build. Baidu app may be running in background.

Try these:

1. Try to close the Baidu app. Goto Settings-> Installed Apps-> Running->find Baidu and close it. Also, follow step2 to prevent app running automatically.
2. Goto security-> permissions->Autostart-> find Baidu and turn off Autostart capability.(This prevents application autostart, application runs only when you open it.)